# Changing SQL account password in specific database

Tags: sql-server, powershell, password

I am trying to change the password for `userId` in a specific database called `LionsDB`.
If I am changing the password manually, I would login into SQL Management Studio using that user account and update the password.

```
$srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $ServerName
$SQLUser = $srv.Logins | ? {$_.Name -eq "$login"};
$SQLUser.ChangePassword($password);
```

With powershell, I cant find the specific logins in the LionsDB database. The above code gives me the logins at server level. Is there anyway to get to the userIDs in specific catalog and change password for them?

Comment: Do you mean a user in a Contained Database? There is no other type of user that has a password at the database level.

Comment: No, I meant sqllogin which has permissions to access only one database.

Comment: In the below code, the windows account has admin permissions to change the sqllogins. In my case, we dont have windows account which has that permissions.   Is there any workaround to change the sqllogin password , by using the the existing password and change it to new password. . http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22767.sql-server-change-the-login-password-using-powershell.aspx,

Comment: You can't change that login's password at the database level. It has absolutely nothing to do with how many databases they have access to.

Comment: Is there way to change the sqllogin user password using powershell, if we have following information (a) SQL Server name (b) SqlLogin name (c) Password (d) newpassword to change to.   I donot have access to windows account which has admin rights on the sql server or on the sqllogin users.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to modify the password using powershell

Answer (score 2):

All password authentication for `userid` is at the server level for a **login**.  Therefore the `LionsDB` database will have **users** but does not have per database password for those users since the **login** is the authentication point.

If you have enough rights, you can change the passwords of the logins and use a different password, but that password would be the same for all databases on your server.

If you need a special login for a database, then you should create another login, e.g. `LionsDB_George` or some such pattern that suits you.  Then you grant that login rights to the `LionsDB` database.

Comment: Thank you,  My script has following parameters  sqllogin and existing password for the sql login. I want to change the password of the sql login using powershell. $srvObj = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" 'servername'
$srvObj.Logins['testusr'].ChangePassword('Test@12345')
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:41
+ $srvObj.Logins['testusr'].ChangePassword <<<< ('Test@12345')
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ChangePassword:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: In the below code, the windows account has admin permissions to change the sqllogins. In my case, we dont have windows account which has that permissions.   Is there any workaround to change the sqllogin password , by using the the existing password and change it to new password. . http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22767.sql-server-change-the-login-password-using-powershell.aspx,